# How to parse jsonb field into columns without keys in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have table `login( id int, meta_skills jsonb)`, but the `jsonb` is not stored in key-value pairs.

The data in the `jsonb` field look like

```json
{
  "Cat1": [
    {
      "Skill_1": 2,
      "Skill_2": 2,
      "Skill_3": 2,
      "Skill_4": 2,
      "Skill_5": 2
    }
  ],
  "Cat2": [
    {
      "Skill_1": 3,
      "Skill_2": 2,
      "Skill_3": 3
    }
  ],
  "Cat3": [
    {
      "Skill_1": 2,
      "Skill_2": 2,
      "Skill_3": 2,
      "Skill_4": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The skills values are random values.
and I want to prepare the data in following format

[image]

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Can you fix the sample?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Removed disturbing comma, some parser don't care, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unnest the levels:

```
SELECT login.id,
       u1.category,
       u3.skill,
       u3.level
FROM login
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(login.meta_skills) AS u1(category,v)
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(u1.v) AS u2(v)
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(u2.v) AS u3(skill, level);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is absolutely working  and first time I have seen the join with JSON functions.